# Powershell to find and rename duplicate values in list items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, listitem

Is there a way using powershell to find duplicate values in a SharePoint list and rename them as "_1", "_2", "_3", etc.

As an example in my test "Products" list I have the following items:

[image]

So for the highlighted items above which have duplicated "SAPMaterial" values, is there a way to use powershell to go through the list to find items that have duplicated values and then if duplicate values are found to then update their "SAPMaterial" value to be like:

- 000000000000227142_1
- 000000000000227142_2

and so on....

The reason I want to find out how to do this with powershell is because we have a list with about 300 items and for quite a lot of these items the values in the "SAPMaterial" column have duplicates. This will take forever doing it manually.

The powershell I have so far is as follows:

```
#Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "siteURL/"
$list = $web.Lists["Products"]

$AllDuplicates = $list.Items.GetDataTable() | Group-Object SAPMaterial | where  
{$_.count -gt 1}
$count = 1
$max = $AllDuplicates.Count
foreach($duplicate in $AllDuplicates)
{
$duplicate.group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$list.GetItemById($_.ID).Delete()}
Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($count / $max * 100) -Activity "$count duplicates   
removed" -Status "In Progress"
$count++
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you simply are looking for tips, they you could start filling a hashtable with `SAPMaterial` as it's key, and on each iteration, check whether one already exists. If not, then you add `_2` and continue. Or you might simply use excel...

Comment: Originally the duplicated items were going to be deleted, but now the new requirement is to rename the duplicated values rather than deleting them as explained above. I have added to my original post the powershell I have so far...

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with Sharepoint cmdlets. What would the command be to change the name of one of your items in the "Products" list? Do you know? I think there may be a way to find the duplicates and loop over them to change each duplicate name

Comment: Basically it is already getting the all the items that have duplicate values for the "SAPMaterial" column... I know that in order to rename the item it has to be updated using the update() method.. the tricky bit is append the "_2", "_3" string to each duplicate value in sequence..

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
#Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "siteURL/"
$list = $web.Lists["Products"]

$AllDuplicateNames = $list.Items.GetDataTable() | Group-Object SAPMaterial | ?{$_.count -gt 1} | %{$_.Name}
foreach($duplicate in $AllDuplicateNames) {
    $dupsaps = $list.Items | ?{$_["SAPMaterial"] -eq $duplicate}
    $count = 1
    foreach($sap in $dupsaps) {
        $sap[“SAPMaterial”] = $duplicate + "_" + $count
        $sap.Update()
        $count++
    }
}
```

Edit: just found a bug should work now but don't have a sharepoint site to test let me know if it works. You should probably backup before running this to be sure.

Comment: There is a typo here which I have corrected "%{$_.Name)" should be "%{$_.Name}". But yeh overall it works great..